# Как настроить отправку форм с сайта

Tags: php, html, email, формы

**Задача:**

Сделать, чтобы пользователи могли отправлять формы с сайта, и чтобы они приходили ко мне на почту.

**Исходные данные:**

1. Есть две формы на сайте хостела.

Первая с выбором номеров и дат.

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <label>Тип:</label>
  <select name="fancySelect" class="makeMeFancy">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Выберите комнату</option>
    <option value="1" data-html-text="общая 6 мест">общая 6 мест</option>
    <option value="2" data-html-text="женская 8 мест">женская 8 мест</option>
    <option value="3" data-html-text="мужская 8 мест">мужская 8 мест</option>
    <option value="4" data-html-text="общая 10 мест">общая 10 мест</option>
  </select>
  <label>Дата заезда:</label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
  <label>Дата отъезда:</label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker2" />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input class="email_form" type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" class="form_btn contact_btn send_btn" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Вторая с формой обратной связи.

```html
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Имя" />
  <input type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Телефон" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <input type="reset" class="contact_btn" value="Очистить форму" />
  <input type="submit" class="contact_btn send_btn" value="Отправить" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

2. Есть файл mail.php

```html
<?php
// Where will you get the forms' results?
define("CONTACT_FORM", 'bphost@yandex.ru');
?>
```

**Что я делал:**

1. Я прогонял код через validator.w3.org и увидел, что есть ошибка в поле action:
   [image: Поле action пустое, видимо должно быть заполнено]
2. Я создавал проверочный файл test.php

```html
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    if (mail("792740321@ya.ru", "Test mail", "Проверка отправки почты")) {
          echo "ok";
    } else {
           echo "error";}
    ?>
```

И получил письмо на почту, что якобы свидетельствует о том, что письма с сайта отправляются.

[image: Такое письмо пришло на почту при тестировании test.php]

3. Вписывал в поле action: mailto:792740321@ya.ru и mail.php. Но это не сработало.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В атрибут `action` надо вписать название скрипта, который будет ответственен за обработку формы. В вашем случае **test.php**.

Если подробнее, то `action` указывает обработчик, к которому обращаются данные формы при их отправке на сервер. В качестве обработчика может выступать CGI-программа или HTML-документ, который включает в себя серверные сценарии (например, Parser). После выполнения обработчиком действий по работе с данными формы он возвращает новый HTML-документ.

Если атрибут `action` отсутствует, текущая страница перезагружается, возвращая все элементы формы к их значениям по умолчанию.

Comment: Наверно не test.php. Потому что я взял его где-то на просторах. А mail.php. Я вставил это значение, но при нажатии кнопки "отправить" я попадаю на пустую страницу http://backpackhostel.ru/mail.php.